# How to read an input given by a driver function

Tags: c, parsing

I am working on a project that will have a driver program redirect its output into the standard input of my program, how would I be able to scan what this program is feeding into my program and have my program respond accordingly. I was thinking of using `scanf`, would that work?

Additional info:
In the first line of the input (out of many lines), the driver gives a number ending in a new line character (\n). Depending on that number, my program will parse the rest of the lines in the input and output a response. Each line will be a string of random letters and my program will need to dynamically allocate memory for each string. These strings will be part of a struct in a linked list.

Comment: `scanf` is certainly one method you can use to read `stdin`.  It's almost certainly not the best choice, and now that `gets` is not part of the language a solid argument could be made that it is the worst choice.  But it could be made to work.  There are many techniques available for reading stdin; which is most appropriate will depend on many details, none of which have been provided in the question.

Comment: @WilliamPursell added some more details

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the input just like regular console input, all the console stdio input calls will work. Just dont try to have a  conversation with it - ie dont go

```
Enter foodle count : dd
Invalid number
Enter Foodle count :
```

becuase there is nobody on the other end

Answer (score 0):

It is generally recommended to use a more robust method than [`scanf`](https://man.openbsd.org/sscanf), as it is full of edge cases, and offers little in the way of recovering from bad input.

[*A beginners' guide away from `scanf()`*](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) is a decent read, although I would offer stricter advice: forget [`scanf`](https://man.openbsd.org/sscanf) exists.

Given the requirement of

> Each line will be a string of random letters and my program will need to dynamically allocate memory for each string. These strings will be part of a struct in a linked list.

POSIX [`getline`](https://man.openbsd.org/getline) (or `getdelim`) is a solid choice, if available. This function handles reading input from a file, and will dynamically allocate memory if requested.

Here is an example skeleton program, with functionality vaguely similar to what you have described.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *input(FILE *file) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t n;

    if (-1 == getline(&line, &n, file))
        return NULL;

    return line;
}

size_t parse_header(char *header) {
    return 42;
}

void use_data(char *data) {
    free(data);
}

int main(void) {
    char *header = input(stdin);
    char *data;

    if (!header)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    size_t lines_expected = parse_header(header);
    size_t lines_read = 0;

    free(header);

    while ((data = input(stdin))) {
        lines_read++;
        use_data(data);
    }

    if (lines_read != lines_expected)
        fprintf(stderr, "Mismatched lines.\n");
}
```

If POSIX is not available on your system, or you just want to explore alternatives, one of the better methods the standard library offers for reading input is [`fgets`](https://man.openbsd.org/fgets). Combined with [`malloc`](https://man.openbsd.org/malloc), [`strlen`](https://man.openbsd.org/strlen), and [`strcpy`](https://man.openbsd.org/strcpy), you have will have roughly implemented [`getline`](https://man.openbsd.org/getline), but do note the caveats in the provided [`fgets`](https://man.openbsd.org/fgets) manual.

While [`scanf`](https://man.openbsd.org/sscanf) is a poor choice for both reading and parsing *input*, [`sscanf`](https://man.openbsd.org/sscanf) remains useful for parsing *strings*, as you have greater control over the state of your data.

The [`strtol`](https://man.openbsd.org/strtol)/[`strtod`](https://man.openbsd.org/strtod) family of functions are usually preferred over [`atoi`](https://man.openbsd.org/atoi) style functions for parsing numbers, though they can be difficult to use properly.